# Ajuda com manipulação de horários de funcionários

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho um situação referente ao horário de entrada e saída de almoço dos funcionários da empresa; preciso limitar o número de funcionários que podem almoçar ao mesmo tempo, pelo menos juntos no intervalo de 15 minutos, então se eu tenho 10 funcionários que sairiam para o almoço às 12:00, então apenas 5 podem almoçar nesse horário e os outros 5 podem almoçar às 12:15 e assim por diante.

O padrão é que a saída para o almoço aconteça 4 horas após a entrada do funcionário e a volta 5 horas após o horário de entrada, podendo a saída para o almoço ser estendida até 6 horas após o horário de entrada, já os horários de entrada e saída não sofrem nenhuma alteração.

Cada "turma" pode sair até 5 funcionários ao mesmo tempo.
 Não encontrei nada semelhante no Stack ou até no Google, então quem tiver um link de algo parecido ou conseguir me auxiliar na query abaixo, agradeço.

```
declare @func as table (id int
                    , nome varchar(255) 
                    , h_entrada datetime 
                    , h_saida datetime
                    , almoco_saida datetime
                    , almoco_volta datetime)

declare @almoco datetime = '12:00:00'
      , @cont int = 0 
      , @qtdNoMesmoHorario int = 5
      , @tempoDif datetime = '00:15:00'

-- =================================
-- funcionários
-- =================================
insert into @func(id, nome, h_entrada, almoco_saida, almoco_volta, h_saida)
Values(1,'joao'      ,'09:00:00',NULL, NULL, '19:00:00'),
      (2,'maria'     ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00'),
      (3,'jose'      ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00'),
      (4,'pedro'     ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00'),
      (5,'thiago'    ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00'),
      (6,'marcos'    ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00'),
      (7,'mauricio'  ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00'),
      (8,'bruna'     ,'09:00:00',NULL, NULL, '19:00:00'),
      (9,'rita'      ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00'),
      (10,'cassia'   ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00'),
      (11,'nadia'    ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00'),
      (12,'douglas'  ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00'),
      (13,'debora'   ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00'),
      (14,'guilherme','09:00:00',NULL, NULL, '19:00:00'),
      (15,'victor'   ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00'),
      (16,'frederico','08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00'),
      (17,'rafael'   ,'09:00:00',NULL, NULL, '19:00:00'),
      (18,'geraldo'  ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00'),
      (19,'edson'    ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00'),
      (20,'vanessa'  ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00')

-- =================================
-- agrupando as qtd dos funcionários 
-- =================================
select @cont = count(*) from @func

while (@cont >= 0)
        begin
        -- =================================
        -- somando 4hs após a entrada
        -- =================================        
        update a 
           set a.almoco_saida = convert(varchar(30),(a.h_entrada + convert(datetime,'04:00:00')),108)
             , a.almoco_volta = convert(varchar(30),(a.h_entrada + convert(datetime,'05:00:00')),108)
          from @func a
set @cont = @cont - 1

end
-- =================================
-- exibindo funcioários
-- =================================
select id
     , nome
     , convert(varchar(30),h_entrada,108) as h_entrada
     , convert(varchar(30),almoco_saida,108) as almoco_saida
     , convert(varchar(30),almoco_volta,108) as almoco_volta
     , convert(varchar(30),h_saida,108) as h_saida
  from @func
 order by h_entrada asc

 select count(*) as qtd 
      , convert(varchar(30),almoco_saida,108) as almoco_saida 
   from @func group by almoco_saida
```

Comment: Se existirem 15 funcionários para sair às 12h, qual o critério para selecionar os 5 primeiros (e sucessivamente)?

Comment: Olá @JoséDiz, esse critério é definido pela RH da empresa, o que acontece é que não pode ter um numero maior de funcionários do que a capacidade do refeitório, então na teoria 15min e 5 por vez é a um fluxo ideal para a entrada e saída do refeitório. Os números são bem maiores, coloquei esses ai apenas como exemplo da situação.

Comment: Outro detalhe, no exemplo eu tenho 6 funcionários que entraram às 08:00, então eles podem almoçar entre 12:00 e 14:00, podendo ser 12:00, 12:15, 12:30, 12:45... 13:45 e 14:00, já os 10 que entraram às 08:30 poderão sair entre 12:00 até 14:30, esses grupos podem se encaixar e podem ser reduzidos... no exemplo que me foi passado 5 estão saindo às 12:00 e 1 às 12:15, depois disso 5 estão saindo às 13:00 e outros 5 às 13:15 e por ultimo 4 estão saindo às 14:00, a situação não parece ser tão complicada, mas não estou conseguindo pensar em uma solução para isso.

Comment: @RicardoSouza o que eu respondei nao ajudou? voce verificou?

Comment: Olá @andreia_sp verifiquei, mas não me atende.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha solução provisória foi fazer a `POG` abaixo, me atende por enquanto mas creio que pode ser melhorada ou até ter uma nova solução para o caso.

```
declare @func as table (id int
                    , nome varchar(255) 
                    , h_entrada datetime 
                    , h_saida datetime
                    , almoco_saida datetime
                    , almoco_volta datetime
                    , prioridade int )

declare @cont int = 0 
      , @qtdNoMesmoHorario int = 4
      , @tempoDif datetime = '00:15:00'
      , @id int

-- =================================
-- funcionários
-- =================================
insert into @func(id, nome, h_entrada, almoco_saida, almoco_volta, h_saida, prioridade)
Values(1,'joao'      ,'09:00:00',NULL, NULL, '19:00:00', null),
      (2,'maria'     ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00', null),
      (3,'jose'      ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00', null),
      (4,'pedro'     ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00', null),
      (5,'thiago'    ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00', null),
      (6,'marcos'    ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00', null),
      (7,'mauricio'  ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00', null),
      (8,'bruna'     ,'09:00:00',NULL, NULL, '19:00:00', null),
      (9,'rita'      ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00', null),
      (10,'cassia'   ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00', null),
      (11,'nadia'    ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00', null),
      (12,'douglas'  ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00', null),
      (13,'debora'   ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00', null),
      (14,'guilherme','09:00:00',NULL, NULL, '19:00:00', null),
      (15,'victor'   ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00', null),
      (16,'frederico','08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00', null),
      (17,'rafael'   ,'09:00:00',NULL, NULL, '19:00:00', null),
      (18,'geraldo'  ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00', null),
      (19,'edson'    ,'08:30:00',NULL, NULL, '18:30:00', null),
      (20,'vanessa'  ,'08:00:00',NULL, NULL, '18:00:00', null)

-- =================================
-- agrupando as qtd dos funcionários 
-- =================================
select @cont = count(*) from @func

while (@cont >= 0)
        begin
        -- =================================
        -- somando 4hs após a entrada
        -- =================================        
        update a 
           set a.almoco_saida = convert(varchar(30),(a.h_entrada + convert(datetime,'04:00:00')),108)
             , a.almoco_volta = convert(varchar(30),(a.h_entrada + convert(datetime,'05:00:00')),108)
             , a.prioridade = case when convert(varchar(30),a.h_entrada,108) = '08:00:00'
                                   then 0
                                   when convert(varchar(30),a.h_entrada,108) = '08:30:00'
                                   then 1
                                   when convert(varchar(30),a.h_entrada,108) = '09:00:00'
                                   then 2 end
          from @func a
set @cont = @cont - 1

end

-- =================================
-- exibindo funcioários
-- =================================
select id
     , nome
     , convert(varchar(30),h_entrada,108) as h_entrada
     , convert(varchar(30),almoco_saida,108) as almoco_saida
     , convert(varchar(30),almoco_volta,108) as almoco_volta
     , convert(varchar(30),h_saida,108) as h_saida
  from @func 
 order by h_entrada asc




-- =================================
-- separando o horario de saida
-- =================================
while exists (select top 1 1
                from @func  
               group by prioridade, almoco_saida 
              having count(*) > @qtdNoMesmoHorario )
begin

        select top 1 @id = id
          from @func a
         where a.almoco_saida = (select top 1 almoco_saida from @func group by prioridade, almoco_saida having count(*) > @qtdNoMesmoHorario order by prioridade, almoco_saida asc)
         order by a.prioridade asc, almoco_saida asc 

        -- somando mais 15min
        update a
           set a.almoco_saida = convert(varchar(30),(a.almoco_saida + convert(datetime,@tempoDif)),108)
             , a.almoco_volta = convert(varchar(30),(a.almoco_volta + convert(datetime,@tempoDif)),108)
          from @func a
         where a.id = @id

end



-- =================================
-- separando o horario de saida / p2
-- =================================
while exists (select top 1 1
                from @func  
               group by almoco_saida 
              having count(*) > @qtdNoMesmoHorario )
begin

        select top 1 @id = id
          from @func a
         where a.almoco_saida = (select top 1 almoco_saida from @func group by almoco_saida having count(*) > @qtdNoMesmoHorario order by almoco_saida desc)
         order by almoco_saida desc 

        -- somando mais 15min
        update a
           set a.almoco_saida = convert(varchar(30),(a.almoco_saida + convert(datetime,@tempoDif)),108)
             , a.almoco_volta = convert(varchar(30),(a.almoco_volta + convert(datetime,@tempoDif)),108)
          from @func a
         where a.id = @id

end




-- ========================
-- resultado final
-- ========================

select id
     , nome
     , convert(varchar(30),h_entrada,108) as h_entrada
     , convert(varchar(30),almoco_saida,108) as almoco_saida
     , convert(varchar(30),almoco_volta,108) as almoco_volta
     , convert(varchar(30),h_saida,108) as h_saida
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by almoco_saida ORDER BY almoco_saida ASC) as qtdPorHorario
     , prioridade

  from @func
 order by prioridade, almoco_saida asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu montei um exemplo selecionando randomicamente. Veja se te ajuda:

```
;WITH grupoHorario AS
(
   SELECT almoco_saida, nome, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY almoco_saida ORDER BY newid()) AS contadorGrupo FROM @func
)
SELECT grupoHorario.contadorGrupo, grupoHorario.nome, convert(varchar(30), almoco_saida,108) almoco_saida FROM grupoHorario WHERE contadorGrupo <= 5
```

Comment: Andreia, sempre que houver dúvida quanto a pergunta, solicite nos comentários, como o José Diz fez. Assim tanto a pergunta quanto a resposta, ficarão mais completas. ;]